# Create button with icons bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create this kind of button in Bootstrap 3:

[image: Button Preview]

The problem is that line between text and icon: I have tried a lot but still didn't get the same look :(

Here is what I have for now

**CSS**

```
.btn-default, .btn-default:active, .btn-default:focus{
    background-color:#fff;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1.0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px 0px rgba(48, 174, 227, 1.0);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 4px 0px 0px rgba(48, 174, 227, 1.0);
    box-shadow:         0px 4px 0px 0px rgba(48, 174, 227, 1.0);
    border-top:1px solid rgba(48, 174, 227, 1.0);
    border-left:1px solid rgba(48, 174, 227, 1.0);
    border-right:1px solid rgba(48, 174, 227, 1.0);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-file-excel-o"></i>Export to excel</a>
```

Maybe the answer is in btn group, but that icon is clickable also :(

Comment: Have you tried to add a span with a `border-left: solid 1px #YOURCOLOR` between your icon and your text? You need to set the width of the span to 1px at least if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: It ok to add that way, but try to add border, you will se what will happen, i want to split that in half with borde full height, the problem with border is that it only gets inside

Comment: Ok let me try for a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

demo - http://www.bootply.com/vVPtGC3QEs

```
a.btn{
 padding:4px 15px;
}

.fa-lg{
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(48, 174, 227, 1.0);
  padding-right: 7px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: initial;
  line-height:28px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but this way you edited a lot of default bootstrap classes

Comment: @Gorostas Well, just keep the Bootstrap classes as they are, create your own class and override some properties, like [this](http://www.bootply.com/cIcHk4ejdR)

Comment: you can add your own classes @Gorostas